# Are Backports On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

A recent [comment by Wizzwizz4](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242/are-questions-about-how-to-build-legacy-software-on-modern-systems-off-topic#comment1044_637) about the issue of [Building Legacy Software on Modern Systems](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242) pointed me to a great question about [building 'legacy' software in their contemporary environment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3246) even through using within an emulation (*1).  I clearly think this is as on-topic as it can get for RC. All parts are contemporary and the problem is exactly the same that would have come up when doing so back then. Fine for me.

Looking closer, this opens another question, as the NS5 he wanted to build in that environment is old by today's viewpoint, but then again from beyond when the emulated environment was actual. So it is basically a backport. Maybe somewhat contemporary, but still a backport. So in conclusion:

**Are backports On-Topic for RC?**

Like in taking some actual/new program of today (definitely not RC) and port it back to an RC related architecture with an RC related OS and RC related tools?

And as follow up, **when would this no longer be true**, where's the Rubicon not to cross?

---

*1 - Which is by the way an awesome project in itself.

---

Standard disclaimer: I will not mark any answer as 'the Answer' as meta is about opinion, not true or false. Eventually when there are more answers (hopefuly), comments and cosiderable up and down vote the consent will be clear.

Answer (score 5):

Is it on-topic: **Yes**

As long everything is like back then - well, maybe except that it's running in an emulated environment on a modern machine which may not only offer faster execution, but also maxed out RAM and additional luxury in handling media as virtual devices and so on. But then again, already an Apple IIc+ did offer a great simplification compared to an original II with a single (or two) drives.

So where is the border to be drawn?

I'd say **when it is about non contemporary tools and details**. For example when it's about the host side of the emulation in use, the compilers used (if not contemporary to the target environment (*1)) or some other (pre) processing done on the 'modern' side.

---

*1 - This goes along with other questions about modern tools for old stuff. For example the 6502 C Compiler as an application would be off-topic, while tweakign code to be compiled with it may be on-topic.